# Kibbud Av V'Eim versus Prevention of a Mitzvah

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

The Mishnah (BM 32a) says that one may not listen to his father if the father tells the son to do something prohibited, such as becoming tamei by entering a cemetery. The Gemara derived this from the passuk (Vayikra 19:3), "A man - his mother and his father he should fear, and My Shabbasos he should guard, I am Hashem." Everyone is chayiv in Hashem's honor.

What if, for instance, it's approaching the end of Zman Krias Shema, and the father asks the son for a cup of water? If the child obeys, he will miss saying Shema in its time, and if he disobeys, he will have violated Kibbud Av V'Eim. (Let's assume that the father will get himself a cup of water if the child refuses, and he will have lost that chance.) The father isn't telling the son to do something prohibited; he's merely telling him to do something, that, upon its performance, will have prevented him from doing another mitzvah.

Note that he has not started either mitzvah yet, and if he does one, he won't be able to do the other.

Comment: עוסק במצוה פטור מן המצוה, so he's pattur anyway.

Comment: @mevaqesh He hasn't actually started either mitzvah yet. I'll edit that to make it more clear.

Comment: @mev He's only oseik vemitzva if he needs to listen to his parent in this case. Otherwise its not a mitzva that he is oseik in. So that's circular

Comment: @DoubleAA Point taken. However, I think it is possible that the Torah is just saying that kibbud av v'em does not trump other mitsvot, so it would not allow me to violate the Torah. That is, there is not special quality to the mitsvah to allow it to supersede other mitsvot. However, the principle of osek b'mitsvah which applies without one mitsvah having some special status would presumably, and one already involved in kibbud av would not need to stop. This seems (I think) like a very reasonable interpretation of the dersasha in isolation (not removing from kibbud av, just

Comment: @DoubleAA not adding). The result, would be that osek b'mitsvah pattur min hamitsvah would apply. So I suppose that indeed, the application of osek b'mitsvah is not the predicate for the argument, but its product. (I think that made sense).

Comment: Theres a Tzad to say: wouldn't getting one's father a cup of water something that is Efshar Laasos Al Yidei Acheirim (i.e other people- though its not the son actively doing it- it could be done by a sheliach) and Kiras Shema is Ei Efshar Laasos Al Yidei Acheirim. Kiryas Shema is dependent on Zman, and Kibbud Av is not dependent on zman. Its the father's decision to choose if he wants to not wait for his son to fulfill his request. So if he doesn't want to wait that's not the son's problem